# Maven embedded tomcat deploy war file

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, spring-mvc

I'm using maven and the embedded tomcat through the tomcat-maven-plugin to run my Spring MVC project. Now I've got a another war file which I also want to run on this tomcat. Is there a way to achieve this? It doesn't seem to work, when I put the war file in the webapps folder of the embedded tomcat.

Comment: Can you supply the pom.xml please :)

Comment: Which part of the pom.xml are you interested in? The whole file is quite big and I don't know if it makes sense to post everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

support of this feature is in snapshot version of the plugin see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-169